Making a big number with decimal part more readable
I want to make a big number more readable but if the number has a decimal part it can't transform the number.
first_number = self.lineEdit.text().replace(",","")
second_number = self.lineEdit_2.text().replace(",","")
            
            
a = float(first_number)-float(second_number)
a = "{:,}".format(a)

self.res.setText(a)


Without showing the input and (expected) output values it's impossible to say what might be wrong with your code

If you want to make a big number more readable but keep its decimal part intact, you can modify your code to only format the integer part of the no. by using float.is_integer() with a condition so:
first_number = self.lineEdit.text().replace(",", "")
second_number = self.lineEdit_2.text().replace(",", "")
            
a = float(first_number) - float(second_number)

# Check if the number has a decimal part
if a.is_integer():
    formatted_number = "{:,.0f}".format(a) 
else:
    formatted_number = "{:,.2f}".format(a)  
    
self.res.setText(formatted_number)

Another approach is to split the number into its integer and decimal parts, format the integer part, and then concatenate them back together, so:
first_number = self.lineEdit.text().replace(",", "")
second_number = self.lineEdit_2.text().replace(",", "")
            
a = float(first_number) - float(second_number)

# Split the number
integer_part, decimal_part = str(a).split('.')

formatted_integer_part = "{:,.0f}".format(float(integer_part))

# Concatenate the integer and decimal parts back together
formatted_number = formatted_integer_part + '.' + decimal_part

self.res.setText(formatted_number)

